# Yocto recipe using cmake cannot find git

Tags: mongodb, cmake, yocto, recipe, openembedded

I am trying to build a recipe for mongo-cxx-driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver). I have working recipes for libbson and mongo-c-driver, which are requirements, but when I try to build mongo-cxx-driver, it fails when trying to clone a git repo.

```
$ bitbake mongo-cxx-driver

| CMake Error at 
/home/hme/projects/platform/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/mongo-cxx-driver/3.1.3-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1805 (message):
|   error: could not find git for clone of EP_mnmlstc_core
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/hme/projects/platform/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/mongo-cxx-driver/3.1.3-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2560 (_ep_add_download_command)
|   src/bsoncxx/third_party/CMakeLists.txt:19 (ExternalProject_Add)
| 
| 
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "MongoDB C++ driver"
SECTION = "libs"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
DEPENDS = "libbson mongo-c-driver git-native"

inherit cmake pkgconfig

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/r${PV}.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "fd1ff0f9b2122225e3b402c2bae30427"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "cb1b371eb34e991b8bfac65146f862cd379aa8f7270c430e5f3d71d843245ed9"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=d2794c0df5b907fdace235a619d80314"

S = "${WORKDIR}/mongo-cxx-driver-r${PV}"
```

If I run:

```
$ bitbake -c devshell mongo-cxx-driver
```

and build manually through the devshell, it works just fine.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Not finding git during configure is a problem you probably shouldn't end up solving: The recipe should not download anything during configure. You should clone the required git repos during fetch (maybe by just adding them to SRC_URI) and find out how to tell the build system the location of the downloaded sources during configure. Alternatively find out if you can tell the build system to use an external (system) component instead and package the other project separately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try to add:

```
OECMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM = "BOTH"
```

to your recipe **after** inherit cmake

Comment: @Nayfe what does OECMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM  = "BOTH" do?

Comment: It allow cmake to search for programs in host sysroot instead of target sysroot only

Answer (score 0):

Package git-native probably is listed in the [ASSUME_PROVIDED](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ASSUME_PROVIDED) variable. If so, you have to add [`git-replacement-native`](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/git/git.inc?id=5157c85776bb8bd7315ef42e6e622aae27ebc79e#n6) as a dependency to your recipe.